# Constructing a smooth atlas for a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be the space $M = \{(x, l) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{RP}^{n-1} | x \in l\}$. I'm trying to construct a smooth atlas for $M$ to show that it is a smooth manifold of dimension $n$. From what I understand, I have to provide a set of charts that cover $M$, which are all smoothly compatible with eachother.

The first chart I was trying to use for this purpose was the following: let $U = M \cap((\mathbb{R}^n -\{0\}) \times \mathbb{RP}^{n-1})$ (open in M), and $U' = \mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$, we then take the chart $\varphi:U\rightarrow U'$ which sends $(x, l) \rightarrow x$. Because the equivalence class $l$ is determined by the point $x$ (since $x \in l$), this is easy to invert and since it's a projection (and M has the product topology) it is continuous.

This covers a large part of M, except for the bits where $x = 0$. I can't seem to find a chart that contains these points.

I think I'm missing something here, or I don't fully understand the question. Any hints/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know to find a smooth atlas for $\Bbb RP^n$? That should help you tremendously.

Comment: I have a smooth atlas for $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ given by (for $1 \leq i \leq n$) $(U_i, \varphi_i)$ where $U_i = \{[x^1 : x^2 : \ldots : x^n] \in \mathbb{R}P^{n-1} | x^i \neq 0\}$ and $\varphi_i : U_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ which sends $[x^1 : \ldots : x^n] $to the point $(\frac{x^1}{x^i}, \ldots, \frac{x^{i-1}}{x^i}, \frac{x^{i+1}}{x^i}, \ldots, \frac{x^n}{x^i})$, but I couldn't quite see how I could extend this to an atlas for M

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: So suppose $l\in U_i$ and $(y,l)\in M$. This means that $l = [x^1,\dots,x^n]$ where $x^i\ne 0$ and $y=t\left(\frac{x^1}{x^i},\frac{x^2}{x^i},\dots,\frac{x^{i-1}}{x^i},1,\frac{x^{i+1}}{x^i},\dots,\frac{x^n}{x^i}\right)$ for some $t\in\Bbb R$.

(Warning: The notation is a bit confusing here.  It's better to use different letters for the point and for your coordinates in $\Bbb R^n$. So I've switched to $y$.)